# Unable to install signed apk from React Native

Tags: android, react-native

After successfully running

./gradlew assembleRelease

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.842 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

I put the "app-release.apk" into the phone, and tried to install it using File Browser. The app icon is showing nowhere.

The installation had text : "App not installed"

[image]

Comment: what version of Android and react-native you are using?

Comment: you may already have a dubug version of this app in your mobile .

Comment: Android 5.1.1 in the phone. react-native 0.1.7

Comment: the debug version is not installed. i have the apk here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tN104uQHSDUWdSTkVTTmJXZVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible answer could be found at: http://mobilityarena.com/fix-application-not-installed-error-androids/

Comment: did you fix the issue

Answer (score 25):

The app was installed in other user. It is seen as uninstalled, but actually it is installed in multi user environment in android.
Press the app in the settings, then press again the app to go into the details. Press the three dots on the top right corner of the screen,  the select uninstall for all users.

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar issue where it was only happening in android 5(lollipop) and below. Turns out my app was partially signed. Running `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs android/app/prod/release/app-prod-release.apk` gave `jar is unsigned`. Turns out the issue was I was not checking the checkboxes for V1 and V2 at the bottom of the 2nd Generate signed APK dialog box. I was leaving out V1.
[image]
Be keen to chek both.

Answer (score 6):

For me disabling the Play Protects from Google Play Store works:

**Following are the steps to disable Play Protect:**

> *To disable Google Play Protect. Open "Play Store" application => tap on Menu button => select "Play Protect" option => Disable the options "Scan device for security threats".*

Comment: I can not solve it by unintall app, even using "adb uninstall com.company.xxx".
But I solved it by disable play protect, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had followed every steps from documentation and other helps from stackoverflow but None helped me . And after series of attempts I found my way out solving the 'App not installed issue'

**Before running**

```
 ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**I also ran**

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Hope it might be a help to you!

Comment: Both are different commands for different purposes. First one is used to generate the apk and other one is used to generate the Bundle

Answer (score 2):

You should check if there are any files related to the app in your device, i had a similar problem and solved it by removing all the cache data from the device. So, make sure to delete the data/cache of the app before unistalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have generated a sign APK. 
To generate sign APK you have to follow the instruction they have given

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

This is not affected to debug build.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still have this problem, try to deactivate in the device configurations google Play protect options. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

check your device storage, same issue happened to me, i deleted some apps and made some space then tried to install, application got installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Redmi 7 pro, there are 2 spaces are available to use, Current working space and 2nd space. I uninstalled an application from my current working space so the setting part(Delete for all users was not available), I went to my 2nd space, application was present there, I uninstalled the application, came back to my working space and installed app again, This solution works for me!!!