# I cant install apk from react-native Its tel me " "App not installed""اا

Tags: react-native

I cant install apk from react-native

Its tel me " "App not installed""

I build it use ing

./gradlew assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.842 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

I STFW

and I find
this

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4421

and this

[Unable to install signed apk from React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994099/unable-to-install-signed-apk-from-react-native)

but Didn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you sign your APK file or did you run `gradlew assembleRelease` only?

Comment: if you already installed a SIGNED APK, and then suddenly RUN in debug, you need to uninstall the current APP that is installed

Comment: I  sign my APK file

Comment: How did you sign the APK file? Can you post what you wrote on the terminal other than `gradlew assembleRelease`?

Comment: I use this to sine my apk
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

and I try unsine apk but its the same

Answer (score 4):

The documentation in the link that you've shared:

> I use this to sine my apk
>   facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html and I try
>   unsine apk but its the same

Is not complete and does not sign your APK file.

As seen [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html):

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate
>   before they can be installed, so to distribute your Android
>   application via Google Play store, you'll need to generate a signed
>   release APK. The [Signing Your Applications](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-manually) page on Android Developers
>   documentation describes the topic in detail. This guide covers the
>   process in brief, as well as lists the steps required to packaging the
>   JavaScript bundle.

`gradlew assembleRelease` will only build/bundle your application for production. You need to sign the APK file yourself.

These are the steps which I take when I want to run my application in production mode:

1. `keytool -genkey -v -keystore key.keystore -alias app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
2. `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..`
3. `jarsigner -verbose -keystore \path_to_key\key.keystore \path_to_apk\app-release-unsigned.apk app-alias`
4. `zipalign -f -v 4 \path_to_apk\app-release-unsigned.apk appName.apk`

Follow these steps and your app should be installed successfully.

Comment: I followed theses steps, but I'm getting :  zipalign: command not found, when running the last command

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisite** - You must have a keystore file, If you don't have then Open cmd run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` follow instructions and you are done.You will have a keystore file. **Now follow these steps**.

1 .On windows `cd android` and then `run gradlew assembleRelease`

2 .Find APK at this location `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk`

3 .Copy this APK to bin folder of jdk installation directory ( for me directory was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) [ Basically in this step we are trying to go to the same directory as jarsigner]

4 .Also Copy your keystore file to this ( `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` ) directory.

5 .Now Open cmd in Administrator mode and run `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin`

6 .Now run

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore 
<<your keystore file name >>  <<your apk file name>> alias_name
```

Here goes your apk , now find your signed apk here `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin` . Run it, Now it should install.