# React-native release apk refuses to install

Tags: android, react-native

I have encounter a problem I am unable to solve, I have followed all steps from:
[Unable to install signed apk from React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994099/unable-to-install-signed-apk-from-react-native) but the ones in Android Studio since I am not using it and the steps needed to sign the apk from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android, I still get the error:

> There was a problem parsing the package

In logcat I get the error:

> 05-23 09:44:23.964  3613  3613 W PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

This error make me thing the error cannot be with signature but there is no manifest file, I searched for it and debug build works.

It only happens with release builds. I hope some of you can help me since I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated the project and repeated the steps, that solved the problem.